# assertion was thrown building AnimatedTheme in flutter Material App

Tags: flutter

I got error when I start up my flutter app but I can't find what the problem is
Here is console error message

```
I/flutter (20105): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════                                                                                   
I/flutter (20105): The following assertion was thrown building AnimatedTheme(duration: 200ms, dirty, state:                                                                                               
I/flutter (20105): _AnimatedThemeState#e868d(ticker active, ThemeDataTween(ThemeData#0c98b → ThemeData#d5c7d))):                                                                                          
I/flutter (20105): 'package:flutter/src/painting/text_style.dart': Failed assertion: line 929 pos 12: 'a == null || b                                                                                     
I/flutter (20105): == null || a.inherit == b.inherit': is not true.

I/flutter (20105): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (20105): #2      TextStyle.lerp (package:flutter/src/painting/text_style.dart:929:12)
I/flutter (20105): #3      TextTheme.lerp (package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart:694:28)
I/flutter (20105): #4      ThemeData.lerp (package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart:1276:28)
I/flutter (20105): #5      ThemeDataTween.lerp (package:flutter/src/material/theme.dart:202:41)
I/flutter (20105): #6      Tween.transform (package:flutter/src/animation/tween.dart:260:12)
I/flutter (20105): #7      Animatable.evaluate (package:flutter/src/animation/tween.dart:53:46)
I/flutter (20105): #8      _AnimatedThemeState.build (package:flutter/src/material/theme.dart:266:19) 
I/flutter (20105): #9      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4619:28) 
I/flutter (20105): #10     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4502:15)
I/flutter (20105): #11     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
I/flutter (20105): #12     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
I/flutter (20105): #13     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2627:33) 
I/flutter (20105): #14     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:20) 
I/flutter (20105): #15     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:284:5)
I/flutter (20105): #16     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1113:15)
I/flutter (20105): #17     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1052:9)
I/flutter (20105): #18     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:968:5)
I/flutter (20105): #22     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:261:10)
I/flutter (20105): #23     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:219:3)
I/flutter (20105): (elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and dart:async)
```

And this is my app in main.dart

```
            return MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
                '/': (BuildContext context) {
                  return Scaffold(
                    body: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "App is not active.",
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            );
```

I am trying to find the problem but Can't find it.
What is the problem?
please help!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works. I run this:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      '/': (BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            "App is not active.",
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  },
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same thing happening in my app. I've been developing it for 2+ years now and this problem crept in some time in the last year, though I cannot pinpoint when or what was done to cause it to happen. It seems that 'something is not quite ready' within the Flutter environment, and so it 'soft crashes'...but then during the next build cycle (or is it 5 more cycles based on the 'elided 5 frames...' message?) everything *is* ready and so the app renders perfectly - never to encounter that error again.

The output stack does not imply a specific user-written line of code caused the issue, and so it is very hard for me to find a fix.  You app is as small as they get and yet it still results in the error. I'm not sure what we can do about this.